# How to redirect 301 with dynamically generated URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Before you say do some research, I have an i know how to Redirect with 301.

However this is quite a specific problem.

so I have a Mod Rewrite in effect:

```
RewriteRule ^/news/article/([^/]*)/$ /news/article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

This outputs the url to /news/article/title/ , however i recently wanted to remove the trailing slash

so the url reads /news/article/title , easily done with this:

```
RewriteRule ^/news/article/([^/]*)$ /news/article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

However now when someone enters /news/article/title/

So my question is there a way to us redirect 301 so when a user enters /news/article/title/ they get directed to /news/article/title

Bare in mind i want this to work for all of the dynamically generated URLs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually make trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/article/([^/]*)/?$ /news/article.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To remove trailing `/` slash from URLs use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I really like the optional slash method! But the remove one is the best i solution i feel

Answer (score 1):

Use the `R=301` flag like this:

```
 RewriteRule ^/news/article/([^/]*)/$ /news/article/$1 [R=301]
 RewriteRule ^/news/article/([^/]*)$ /news/article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

See [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) for more details about the flags